# Wifi not working after installing pop os

Tags: wifi, pop-os

I am new to Linux, I installed pop os today on a windows laptop. but after the install for some reason, the wifi stopped working. It connects to the network but doesn't load anything and it has a question mark on the wifi icon most of the time. I have already tried everything this website says but nothing seems to work. [Link](https://support.system76.com/articles/wireless). My network controller is a Broadcom BCM4313 802.11bgn. When i connect the Ethernet cable it works and when i remove it it stops working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check dmesg, but i can almost guarantee you it’s because you have mismatched drivers. [This Website](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43) should help you figure out which driver you need. Keep in mind you may need to also blacklist the driver which is set to load by default. You then should be able to install the proper driver by using your distros package manager.